# Ansible having problem authenticating with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: ansible, google-kubernetes-engine

We are using [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) to deploy an image to [Google Kubernetes Cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine) (GKE).

We have setup Ubuntu 20.04 and Python 3.8.5.

playbook.main.yml:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    k8s_file_path: /home/pesinn/Documents/...
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  roles:
    - k8s
```

main.yml:

```
- name: First Deployment
  k8s:
    kubeconfig: /home/pesinn/.kube/config
    src: "{{k8s_file_path}}/deployment.yml"
```

When trying to deploy the image defined in deployment.yml file, by running the playbook, we get this error:

> kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: cmd-path: process returned 1
> Cmd: /home/pesinn/y/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud config config-helper --format=json
> Stderr: WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].
> ERROR: (gcloud.config.config-helper) You do not currently have an active account selected.
> Please run:
> $ gcloud auth login

What we've already done

- Initialized the cloud: `gcloud init`
- Logged in and chosen a project `gcloud auth login`
- Run `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path_to_service_account_key.json"`
- Run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials {gke_project} --region {region}`
- Run the playbook `sudo ansible-playbook playbook.main.yml -vvv`
- Run `gcloud config config-helper --format=json` on the local machine without any problems

What is very strange here is that we're logged in for sure. We can access the GKE cluster through kubectl command on the local machine. However, Ansible complains about us not being logged in. Also, in the error logs, we see that it is trying to open /root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default. Our default config file is, on the other hand, located in the home folder.

This error occurs randomly. Sometimes Ansible can detect our login and deploys the image, but sometimes it gives us this error. Both scenarios can happens without any code changes being made.

Comment: If your default config file is in "the home folder", I guess you played all the set of manual example commands as a normal user. In this case, why are you using `become: true` in your playbook to become root ? Even worse: why are your launching your playbook with `sudo` ?

Comment: Thanks for helping out! It works when deleting `become: true` and then drop `sudo` from the running command.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, ansible does not use GCP's default environment variables for authentication.
You can set

```
GCP_AUTH_KIND
GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE
GCP_SCOPES
```

`GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE` is the equivalent of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`

Reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html#providing-credentials-as-environment-variables